# GRUB Boot Recover Windows Part

Tags: grub

I have a computer which I installed Linux first and then Windows. To be able to recover my GRUB I mount Linux anyway. Lastly, I typed  `sudo update -grub`. After that, I am not able to boot the computer into Windows.  Is there any way for dual booting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use boot repair if you want an easy gui based solution.

Else check this link this is given for ubuntu but it is valid for other venders too.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows